# F# Add multiple constructor overloads that call the base class constructor

Tags: inheritance, constructor, f#, constructor-overloading

I'm trying to create a dictionary with structural equality in F# and I want to pass through several dictionary constructor overloads.

In C# this would look like

```cs
class StructuralDictionary<Key, Value> : Dictionary<Key, Value> where Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    public StructuralDictionary() : base() { }
    public StructuralDictionary(IDictionary<Key, Value> dict) : base(dict) { }
    public StructuralDictionary(IEqualityComparer<Key> keyComparer) : base(keyComparer) { }
}
```

The F# docs have [section demonstrating this usecase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/inheritance#constructors-and-inheritance), but I can't get it to compile

```ml
type StructuralDictionary<'key, 'value when 'key:equality> =

    new (dictionary:IDictionary<'key,'value>) = { inherit Dictionary<'key,'value>(dictionary) }
    new () = { inherit Dictionary<'key, 'value> () }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. I was missing a `inherit` at the top

```ml
type StructuralDictionary<'key, 'value when 'key:equality> =
    inherit Dictionary<'key, 'value> // <--- This has to be here

    new (dictionary:IDictionary<'key,'value>) = { inherit Dictionary<'key,'value>(dictionary) }
    new () = { inherit Dictionary<'key, 'value> () }
```

I got a bit confused because I started with a primary constructor like

```ml
type StructuralDictionary<'key, 'value when 'key:equality> () =
    inherit Dictionary<'key, 'value> ()

    new (dictionary:IDictionary<'key,'value>) = { inherit Dictionary<'key,'value>(dictionary) }
```

But that doesn't work. So I tried to move the primary constructor down, but also moved the inheritance declaration so it still didn't compile.

It turns out to overload constructors you must have inherits at the top of the type declaration but you must not specify a primary constructor at the top.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the implicit constructor syntax, all other constructors will have to call the implicit constructor (and, indirectly, will end up calling the same constructor of the base class).

In your example, you could define an implicit constructor that takes `IDictionary` as the argument and call it with an empty dictionary from the other constructor:

```
type StructuralDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue when 'TKey:equality>
    (dictionary:IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue>) =
  inherit Dictionary<'TKey, 'TValue>(dictionary)
  new () = StructuralDictionary(dict [])
```

This may have some small overhead in contrast to just calling the base constructor without arguments (you are allocating an empty dictionary), but it lets you use all the other convenient features of implicit constructors, so it is probably worth it.

Comment: That's good to know.
However, if I'm understanding this correctly, it wouldn't allow me to forward different parameter lists to the base constructor. Part of my issue here is that not all base class construction scenarios are mappable. When you refer to benefits of implicit constructors, what do you mean? Like initialization code outside the constructors?

Comment: You are correct - this would not work if you had two base constructors taking different sets of arguments. The benefits I mean are mainly using `let` bindings in the implicit constructor for private fields and initialization code.